# M2 | ci6.googleusercontent.com gmail proxy server stopping images to load in email templates

Tags: magento2.3, email-templates, media-images, proxy

I am having gmail proxy server issue for showing images in email templates.

> At the start of image URL which is
> http://localhost/pub/media/email/images/logo.png
>
> this is getting appended
> https://ci6.googleusercontent.com/proxy/tuG-pi...

Like: https://ci6.googleusercontent.com/proxy/tuG-pitMvoq3PwS0FSL5T-pV7Wh_9PffwfBhgEW_NuEAfWNG5rld6qaGEGRa0-pg50C9akGBwpPr3gx7U3IpT-jh_rnZUtn2MjK-7MuTJqXvFM0UHJWVe-Vz-86HvTVgkDcERAjIYt1ZWxOv7BYUawrPc42zYxEJkVNF=s0-d-e1-ft#http://localhost/pub/static/version1614839350/frontend/CustomTheme/default/en_US/images/email/logo.png

I found this remedy https://stackoverflow.com/a/51643787/10193644 but not sure how can I send HTTP header code 200 for sales emails (for example "new_order" email templete)

I have overridded the default order email temple from theme as:

> app/design/frontend/[Vendor_Name]/[Theme_Name]/Magento_Sales/email/order_new.html

Looking for your valuable ideas as solution, Thanks